# Probability of Transitive Tournament

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

n people participate in a tournament, every 2 people compete each other.
A tournament is called transitive if it fulfills the following property:

> For every combination of three players, if player A beat player B and
> player B beat player C, then player A also beat player C.

- Show that a tournament is transitive if and only if there is an arrangement of the participants such that a certain participant defeated another participant if and only if he appears before him in the arrangement, and this arrangement is unique.
- Calculate the probability that random tournament is transitive, as the quotient of the number of transitive tournaments and the number of tournaments in general.

**Thoughts** 
 I can prove the first part by finding an arrangement according to the number of wins of each player and doing induction, but not sure how to apply the induction step?. 
 In the second part, according to the definition of a tournament graph I will get $\left|\Omega\right|=2^{{n \choose 2}}$ but how do I find the event?